# Trying to get data from web to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from Fangraphs to google sheets, and I was having success until I started trying to use the split stats. Now I can't get it to import properly. I'm trying to get the information from [here](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=9&splitArrPitch=&position=P&autoPt=true&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2021-03-01&endDate=2021-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&sort=-1,1&pageitems=200&pg=0).

I have tried

```
=IMPORTHTML(
  "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=9&splitArrPitch=&position=P&autoPt=true&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=1&startDate=2021-03-01&endDate=2021-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&sort=-1,1&pageitems=200&pg=0", 
  "table", 
  any number I have tried
)
```

But I can't get the info to show on google sheets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong on your end, but the information is loaded asynchronously and are not available when the page is loaded. Take a look at this [post on Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun).

Comment: Thank you! I think a I found a work around, Learning as I go, on to the next question Appreciate your help!